# AppleScript to click "Don't Save" on window close

Tags: applescript, savefiledialog

I am using AppleScript to close windows in Google Sketchup as follows:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "SketchUp" to close window 1'
```

When I close the window, the program prompts me to save, and there is a dialog box with buttons "Don't Save", "Cancel", and "Save...".

How do I make my script click on the "Don't Save" button in this situation?

Also, if there is a better way of closing the window, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "SketchUp" to close window 1 saving no'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t have to use Applescript, you could enable <kbd>tab</kbd> to hop through the buttons in the save dialog.

First press  <kbd>cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>w</kbd> to close the window, than try to cycle through the buttons by pressing  <kbd>tab</kbd>. If you do not see a little blue highlight hopping around the buttons, press ( <kbd>fn</kbd> + ) <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to enable this feature. You should now see a blue highlight around the leftmost (in Sketchup: "do not save") button. You can navigate over the highlighted button with pressing  <kbd>tab</kbd> and select the highlighted button with pressing  <kbd>space</kbd>.

Comment: How would you programmatically send these keystrokes to Sketchup without AppleScript?

Comment: I´m sorry, I guess I misunderstood the "if there is a better way of closing the window"-part of your question.